# Is there a way not to include structured markup in HTML directly?

Tags: html, json-ld, structured-data

I've added json-ld structured data to my website, which caused the page size to increase from 80kb to 120kb, this hurts the page load speed as well as decreases the text to code ratio. Is there a better way to provide structured data, not including it in the html directly?

Comment: Adding it in the HTML *directly* (with Microdata/RDFa instead of JSON-LD) would improve it, though, as you don’t have to duplicate the content.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it an old way of markup, google recommends JSON-LD now, also may I mix JSON-LD with microdata, because it will take to migrate all website to microdata?

Comment: Google supports all three syntaxes (Microdata, RDFa, JSON-LD). That they recommend to use JSON-LD doesn’t mean that they recommend *not* to use the other two syntaxes. I think there are [only two reasons](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110150/17633) why Google recommends JSON-LD; if they don’t apply to you, it’s fine to use another syntax. -- I would recommend to go with RDFa; in case it’s ever needed, you can automatically generate JSON-LD from this RDFa (not possible the other way around). Mixing several syntaxes is possible, but can be problematic -- it depends.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, will do some more research, but I think this will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer this question.

I don't think you can add your json-ld structured data on external source like javascript or css, but you can try to move up your json-ld structured data from your header into your footer of your web page.

SEO Quake chrome extension doesn't give a warning for this kind of implementation.

I hope this can help up you to increase your page load speed but maybe still a weak answer because of the text to code ratio won't be decreased as per your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, btw placing in header or footer won't make much sense I think...

Comment: Your welcome... At least you can try it. It has same reason with why do people move up their javascript file into their website's footer.

Comment: Yes I think it will speed up rendering at least